# Rails: Amazon s3 direct upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

I'm very confused about the block of code that I posted below in-between the script tags. As far as I know, javascript is supposed to go in-between the script tags, but the author is putting HTML. My sublime editor seems to agree with me since it is off-coloring (not the usual markup colors) all the HTML in-between the script tags. I think that this portion of the code is supposed to provide an "upload" button but when I attempt to load the page via localhost nothing appears. Could someone please tell me what the author is doing by putting HTML in-between the script tags and also tell me how to get the code to work?

Thanks a bunch (P.S. I'm new to Rails so I apologize If I'm missing something obvious).

```
<div id="uploads_container"></div>
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div id = "upload_{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
<h5>{%=o.name%}</h5>
<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: I just realized that x-tmpl allows you to use javascript objects with other languages. Yet no code appears still, even when I hardcore some text in there using paragraph tags, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me what the author is doing by putting HTML in-between the script tags and also tell me how to get the code to work?

This block of code is intended to be used as a template by whichever JavaScript templating library the tutorial is using.

Somewhere, there will be a chunk of JavaScript code that looks for a script with the id `template-upload`, fills in the placeholders (i.e. `{}`) with the necessary values and attaches the output to the DOM.